# geometry.attributes is null in three.js 0.124

Tags: three.js

I am working on Three.js to build a terrain as showed below.

```
    const segment = 25
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(dimension, dimension, segment, segment)
    for (let i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
            const idx = i * vertices
            const fVal = (simplex.noise2D(ni, nj) + 1) / 2
            const sVal = (0.5 * simplex.noise2D(ni * 2, nj * 2) + 1) / 2
            const tVal = (0.25 * simplex.noise2D(ni * 4, nj * 4) + 1) / 2
            const vtx = (fVal + sVal + tVal) / 2.15
            geometry.attributes.position.setY(idx, Math.pow(vtx, 2.5) * 350)
    }

The application throws out an error saying: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position'), which points out geometry.attributes is null.
```

My three.js version is 0.124 and currently I don't want to update it to 0.125 since there are many features relying on current version.

How would I solve this issue.

Update, at last I update it to 0.125 version, and it works

Comment: In r124, `PlaneGeometry` is `Geometry`, not `BufferGeometry`, thus there is no `geometry.attributes` property at all. If you want to work with `BufferGeometry` version of a plane, then use `PlaneBufferGeometry`.